# why this command fail? rm and g++ command?

Tags: c++, linux, shell

```
rm *.o | g++ -c test.cpp | g++ test.o main.cpp
```

result :

```
rm: cannot remove '*.o': No such file or directory
g++: error: test.o: No such file or directory
```

why?

Comment: Are you sure those `|` shouldn't be `&&` ?

Comment: Likely true, but this is not the reason at least for the first error message ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems: (a) you may not have any .o files to delete, and (b) you are using pipes inappropriately. Try:

```
rm *.o &> /dev/null ; g++ -c test.cpp && g++ test.o main.cpp
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 ^^
       ignore any error               only try to link if
       message and                    compile is successful
       continue regardless
```

Answer (score 1):

The first error message says that there are no files ending in .o which can be removed.

The second message says that g++ does not find a file test.o to process.

While the reason for the first one is obvious, I would not have expected the second message in this case, unless the compiler would also output compilation error messages:

While the usage of a pipe, as WhozCraig correctly pointed out in his comment, doesn't make sense, g++ does not, for all I know, read the file to be compiled from stdin, nor does it write the object file to stdout.

Hence, either the file should be compiled (notwithstanding the fact that the g++ command are placed in a pipe), or you should have received additional error messages about either compilation errors or about a missing input file.

For a first run, replace the pipe symbols by semicolons, run it again and post the complete output you receive.

You could also use && here as he suggests, but I don't see a good reason why the compilation should not be performed if no .o file exists.